# Tizen Return Code 1009

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app

Using Tizen IDE I tried to run my WGT file as a web application butI received this error message. I tried to do some research and couldn't find what return code 1009 indicated. If anyone has a general understanding of what causes this error, I would greatly appreciate it.

[image]

Comment: Try uninstalling the app from command line: `sdb uninstall <pkg_id>`

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue and managed to fix it by uninstalling the package from Tizen emulator. Here is a short instruction:

1. Launch the emulator.
2. Switch to old-fashioned remote controller - Ctrl+Shift+K.
3. Find the app to be uninstalled.
4. Click the green button on the remote controller.
5. In the context menu click "delete".

After this we were able to reinstall / run the app in debug mode. We believe that the issue was somehow related to certificates that we update from time to time.